# Remove duplicates from basenames in two files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have two long lists of filenames, and I want to merge these two by excluding duplicated filenames in the sense of basename. For example, I have something like

```
../data_folderA/file_1 
../data_folderA/file_2
...
../data_folderA/file_n
```

in list A and

```
../data_folderB/file_1 
../data_folderB/file_2
../data_folderC/fffile_1 
../data_folderC/fffile_2
...
../data_folderC/fffile_n
```

in list B. I want to exclude the duplicated file file_1 and file_2 in the merged list. Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: do you mean you do not want to see *any* occurence of a file whose basename is a duplicate? or just see *one* occurence (and if so, which one?)

Comment: Does either list contain any duplicated basenames? i.e., could list B contain both `../data_folderB/file_3` and `../data_folderC/file_3` ?

Answer (score 4):

in awk you could do

```
awk -F "/" ' 
     { filenames[$NF]=$0 ; occurence[$NF]++ ; }
 END { for (basename in filenames) 
       {   if (occurence[basename] == 1) 
           {   print filenames[basename]
           }
       }
     } '  listA  listB
```

There is of course a terser way to do this, and I abuse "{ ... }", but I hope it's clear:

- we first fill a "filenames[]" array using index name $NF (= LAST field in the line using "/" as separator, ie the basename).
- And we also count the number of $NF we saw, thanks to the occurence[] array (if more than "1", we only have the latest one in filenames[$NF], and we have occurence[$NF]>1)
- Then we only print those that have a occurence == 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your lists in some files `path/to/list1.txt` and `/path/to/list2.txt` you can use a simple Python program to add the two lists in two Python lists and then set union them as follows:

```
files1 = [line.strip() for line in open('/path/to/list1.txt')]
files2 = [line.strip() for line in open('/path/to/list2.txt')]

uniqueset = set(files1).union(set(files2))
```

The uniqueset will contain the unique files. May be you want to exclude the common names altogether from the resulting list. In that case you can do the following:

```
 uniqueset = set(files1).symmetric_difference(set(files2))
```